# how to just get the HTML output structure of a site

Tags: html, curl, web-scraping, wget

I guess it shows my kookiness here but how do I just get the HTML presentation of a website?  for ex., I am trying to retrieve from a Wix site the HTML structure (what is actually being viewed by a user on the screen) but instead I am getting lots of scripts that exist on the site. I am doing a small code test for scraping.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Most likely you can't without behaving like a browser and running those scripts, so look for ways to automate a browser instead of doing the work yourself.

Comment: Dark Falcon is right. Selenium is a possibility to automate a browser. But it's years ago, that I used it, so I can't give you a detailed answer.

Comment: Is that a package that I can use in Java?

Comment: Would java be your preferred language? Or would python be ok?

Comment: Have to be Java for now, but python is on my to do list :-)

Comment: Alright, hangon I'll get an answer together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright,here we go. Sorry for the delay.

I used [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) to load the page, that way I could make sure to capture all the markup even if it's loaded by ajax. Make sure to grab the standalone library, that threw me for a loop.

Once the html is retrieved I pass it to [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) which I use to iterate through the document and remove all the text.

Here's the example code:

```
// selenium to grab the html
// i chose to use this to get anything that may be loaded by ajax
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

// jsoup for parsing the html
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.parser.Parser;
import org.jsoup.helper.Validate;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.nodes.TextNode;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;


public class Example  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a new instance of the html unit driver
        // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface, 
        // not the implementation.
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        // And now use this to visit stackoverflow
        driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/");

        // Get the page source
        String html =  driver.getPageSource();


        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());

        for (Element el : doc.select("*")){
            if (!el.ownText().isEmpty()){
                for (TextNode node : el.textNodes())
                    node.remove();
            }
        }

        System.out.println(doc);

        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Not sure if you wanted to get rid of the attribute tags as well, currently they are left. However, it's easy enough to modify the code so that some or all of the attribute tags are removed too.

Comment: OK, so I finally got it to run, but, I still just get the source of the page and not sure how do you just get the actual HTML being rendered to the screen (I guess after the browser/driver engine runs it).  I get same result as if I telnet with a GET.

Comment: @Basixp is the code running correctly, what kind of output are you getting? Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qqzzmdt4/) of what is returned for me.

Comment: I am running it only up to the getPageSource() without the Jsoup thingie against http://797967.wix.com/mysite and it seems like I am getting the html source but before its being presented to the screen.

Comment: if you go to inspect element on chrome lets say, you will see a section like <product-title data-hook="product-title" 
    ng-if="$ctrl.showProductName()" 
    ng-model="$ctrl.ngModel" 
    class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">

    <h3 class="title product-title" data-hook="title-wrapper">
       <a data-hook="title">Product 1</a>
    </h3>
</product-title> but no where in the returned html I can see this structure.

Comment: Oh I see it's angularjs, have a look at [protractor](https://angular.github.io/protractor/) that should help you get at the content.

Comment: OK just to close the thread here, it seems like the WebDriver does not actually "execute" the dynamic script but rather just gives back what a standard telnet / HTTP GET command will return, which is prior to the browser executing all the scripts, Ajax etc...  but @bmcculley that much for all your time, will check your other suggestion, cheers !

Answer (score 0):

If you just require the content from the page, you can just use `?_escaped_fragment_` on every url to get the static content.

_escaped_fragment_ is an standard approach used for Ajax crawling for crawling the pages which are dynamic in nature or are generated / rendered at client side.

Wix based websites support `_escaped_fragment`.